# AES_DECRYPT() returns null fields codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

I have an encrypted table on mysql, when i run the following query on the command window i get the expected results:

```
select AES_DECRYPT(field,'key') as field from table
```

when i run the same query from codeigniter:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(field,'".$key."') AS field from table")
```

i get rows with rare characters and null rows

```
array(171) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["nombre"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["nombre"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(17) "�O������aǥbnp/"
```

Im using xampp
the default character set on php.ini is set to utf8
the character set of the database is set to utf8

I have faced a similar issue before, but the query was returning hex values so i used utf8_encode() to display the content and everything was working fine. I updated xampp and now this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$key` is a string then this might work

```
$this->db->query("SELECT AES_DECRYPT(field, $key) AS field from table");
```

When you run `select AES_DECRYPT(field,'key') as field from table;` in the command window you are providing a string literal to the second argument of `AES_DECRYPT`. Not the case when using a var that is a string.